# How can I stop seeing the migration cape on other players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

### Background

The Migration cape was rolled out to all eligible players who bought Minecraft before December 1, 2020 and migrated their Mojang or legacy account to a Microsoft account.
[image: Minecraft Migration cape]

### Turning off the Migration cape

I want to stop seeing the Migration cape on other players.

You can turn off your own cape via this setting in `Options > Skin Customization`:
[image: Disable your cape via Options]

...but there is no option to stop seeing the migration cape on *other* players.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Texture pack editing and/or mods are both acceptable solutions, as long as they also revert the elytra into the original design. If a solution requires disabling the ability to see *all* capes, that is undesirable but acceptable.

Thank you!

Comment: This might be overkill, but there are hacked clients that would possibly let you choose to render the capes or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capes can be removed by modifying the game's Core Shaders via a [resourcepack](https://www.mediafire.com/file/bzw70ha3vji7jbv/NoCape.zip/file) (possible 1.17 and onwards).

---

The `rendertype_entity_solid.fsh` shader controls the cape rendering. The cape can be made entirely transparent by inserting this bit of code:

```
if (hasCape){
    discard;
}
```

Like so:

```
#version 150

#moj_import <fog.glsl>

uniform sampler2D Sampler0;

uniform vec4 ColorModulator;
uniform float FogStart;
uniform float FogEnd;
uniform vec4 FogColor;

in float vertexDistance;
in vec4 vertexColor;
in vec4 lightMapColor;
in vec4 overlayColor;
in vec2 texCoord0;
in vec4 normal;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {
    
    vec4 color = texture(Sampler0, texCoord0) * vertexColor * ColorModulator;
    bool hasCape = textureSize(Sampler0, 0) == ivec2(64,32);
    if (hasCape){
        discard;
    }
    color.rgb = mix(overlayColor.rgb, color.rgb, overlayColor.a);
    color *= lightMapColor;
    fragColor = linear_fog(color, vertexDistance, FogStart, FogEnd, FogColor);
}
```

---

The `rendertype_armor_cutout_no_cull.vsh` shader controls armor rendering, including elytra. The cape texture can be removed from the elytra by inserting the following code by [McTsts](https://github.com/McTsts):

```
    // removes cape elytras
    vec2 texSize = textureSize(Sampler0,0);
    if( texSize.x == 64 && texSize.y == 32 && // check if size matches a cape
            texture(Sampler0, vec2(0.0, 1.0/32.0)).a == 1.0 && texture(Sampler0, vec2(12.0/64.0, 16.0/32.0)).a == 1.0 && // check if skin transparent pixels have color
            (   // support both types of cape texture
                (texture(Sampler0, vec2(0.0, 18.0/32.0)) == vec4(1.0) && texture(Sampler0, vec2(0.99, 0.99)) == vec4(1.0) && texture(Sampler0, vec2(0.99, 0.0)) == vec4(1.0)) // for capes filled with white, check for white pixels
                || (texture(Sampler0, vec2(25.0/64.0, 25.0/32.0)).a == 0.0 || texture(Sampler0, vec2(30.0/64.0, 10.0/32.0)).a == 0.0 || texture(Sampler0, vec2(9.0/64.0, 25.0/32.0)).a == 0.0)  // otherwise check of transparent pixels
            )
    ) gl_Position = vec4(0.0);
```

Like so:

```
#version 150

#moj_import <light.glsl>

in vec3 Position;
in vec4 Color;
in vec2 UV0;
in vec2 UV1;
in ivec2 UV2;
in vec3 Normal;

uniform sampler2D Sampler0;
uniform sampler2D Sampler2;

uniform mat4 ModelViewMat;
uniform mat4 ProjMat;

uniform vec3 Light0_Direction;
uniform vec3 Light1_Direction;

out float vertexDistance;
out vec4 vertexColor;
out vec2 texCoord0;
out vec2 texCoord1;
out vec4 normal;

void main() {
    gl_Position = ProjMat * ModelViewMat * vec4(Position, 1.0);

    vertexDistance = length((ModelViewMat * vec4(Position, 1.0)).xyz);
    vertexColor = minecraft_mix_light(Light0_Direction, Light1_Direction, Normal, Color) * texelFetch(Sampler2, UV2 / 16, 0);
    texCoord0 = UV0;
    texCoord1 = UV1;
    normal = ProjMat * ModelViewMat * vec4(Normal, 0.0);
    
    // removes cape elytras
    vec2 texSize = textureSize(Sampler0,0);
    if( texSize.x == 64 && texSize.y == 32 && // check if size matches a cape
            texture(Sampler0, vec2(0.0, 1.0/32.0)).a == 1.0 && texture(Sampler0, vec2(12.0/64.0, 16.0/32.0)).a == 1.0 && // check if skin transparent pixels have color
            (   // support both types of cape texture
                (texture(Sampler0, vec2(0.0, 18.0/32.0)) == vec4(1.0) && texture(Sampler0, vec2(0.99, 0.99)) == vec4(1.0) && texture(Sampler0, vec2(0.99, 0.0)) == vec4(1.0)) // for capes filled with white, check for white pixels
                || (texture(Sampler0, vec2(25.0/64.0, 25.0/32.0)).a == 0.0 || texture(Sampler0, vec2(30.0/64.0, 10.0/32.0)).a == 0.0 || texture(Sampler0, vec2(9.0/64.0, 25.0/32.0)).a == 0.0)  // otherwise check of transparent pixels
            )
    ) gl_Position = vec4(0.0);
}
```

---

[Resourcepack download](https://www.mediafire.com/file/bzw70ha3vji7jbv/NoCape.zip/file)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this **doesn't seem to be possible** as of right now. Upon some research, I can't find any mods to do it and, since migrator capes are given officially by Mojang (and so they display on any client), I highly doubt there will *ever* be any official way either. However, making a mod to do this is likely pretty easy, so it's possible that somebody will eventually make one that'll do what you want.

Apologies if this doesn't really answer your question, but there isn't really much else to say.